# Vertical left branch in qtree

Tags: tikz-qtree, qtree

Let's consider a really simple tree like the following :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{qtree, tikz-qtree, tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree 
    [.XP
    [.X ] [.compl ] ]   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In its natural form, it looks like two symetric branches /\ . How can I make it looks like |\ (or eventually the reverse, /|). In other words, given that I only use binary branches, how can I "tell my tree" to put a branch straight, and the other one oblic left of oblic right? I may eventually want to draw a tree like this :

```
 |\
 |\
/|
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know with `qtree` but with [`forest`](http://catn.org/pkg/forest) it's easy with options `calign=first` or `calign=last`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
%\usepackage{qtree, tikz-qtree, tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{forest}
    [XP, for tree={calign=first}
    [X [a [A, calign=last [B] [D]] [B]] [b] [c]] [compl, calign=last [A] [B] ] ]   
\end{forest}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I never heard of this package. It seems very powerful. Maybe I'll start using only it.
One small thing though, how do you do to print the bracket symbol on the tree (I want my node to print `[compl]` instead of simply `compl` ?

Comment: @BonyHoax, This one is easy, use `{[compl]}`.